# Modeling techniques for simulating the electronic and structural properties of Transition Metal Dichalcogenide nanotubes

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, transition-metals, nanostructures, dichalcogenides

Dear Matter Modeling Stack Exchange community,
I am currently working on calculating the electronic and structural properties of Transition Metal Dichalcogenide (TMD) nanotubes using DFT, with a specific focus on the **1T'-MoTe2**. I would like to inquire about the best approach and tools available for preparing an input file, such as a **POSCAR** file, for a nanotube structure derived from the 2D structure of 1T'-MoTe2.
I have attempted to use the **c2x** tool https://www.c2x.org.uk/nanotube.html to generate the nanotube structure. However, I encountered a problem with this approach because the c-axis in 1T'-MoTe2 is not perpendicular to the a-b plane, which is due to the distorted nature of the structure.
Considering this challenge, I am seeking your guidance on alternative tools or methods that can be employed to construct an accurate nanotube structure starting from the distorted 2D structure of 1T'-MoTe2.

Thank you in advance for your expertise and assistance!

Comment: In the past, I used these two sites to generate nanotubes: [TubeGen](https://turin.nss.udel.edu/research/tubegenonline.html) and [TubeASP](https://nanoten.com/science/tubeASP/index.html).

Comment: I am aware of those websites, but they don't support the thing I am looking for. Firstly, they are mainly for carbon nanotubes and can only support hexagonal or cubic cells. Besides, as I mentioned in the question the lattice I am trying to roll into a nanotube is distorted octahedral, so the c plane is not perpendicular to the ab plane. I have tried c2x and vaspkit and both didn't work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend ChiralTube: http://chiraltube.com

The code (and simulations) were covered in a recent publication:
["Chiraltube, rolling 2D materials into chiral nanotubes"](https://doi.org/10.1039/D3NA00301A)

The code is also available on GitHub: https://github.com/Chema-dac/chiraltube

The paper covers, carbon nanotubes, phosphorene, but also $\ce{MoS2}$ and $\ce{Ti3C2}$. I haven't had much time to explore it, but the `UnitCellExamples` include QuantumEspresso input, "special XYZ", and VASP.

Here's $\ce{MoS2}$ in "special xyz" format:

```
3
####comment####
S 1.5905260315876495465 0.9182342920325894154  6.565586833
S 1.5905260315876495465 0.9182342920325894154  3.434413167
Mo 0.0000142401699290626 1.8365313040729291692 5.000000000000
alat
1.0
mass S 28.09
mass Mo 95.95
supercell
 3.181079696    0.000000000   0.000000000
-1.590540237    2.754889038   0.000000000
 0.000000000    0.000000000  10.000000000
cartesian coordinates
```

The website writes the "special xyz" by default, but you can use VASP input and output from the Python script:

`python chiraltube.py <inputfile> -indexn5m10 -VASPin -VASPout`

It also gives help with:

`python chiraltube.py -h`

For example, a supercell of $\ce{MoS2}$ 5,5 nanotube in POSCAR rendered by Avogadro:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing the article. For people who might be interested, Chiraltube is the fastest approach. You can create a tubular structure using c2x tool in a few steps: put atoms into absolute coordinates, adjust lattice vectors for perpendicular planes, then make the tube. Chiraltube automates this process with distortion cells, requiring only chiral or achiral vectors. However, I am just concerned that by doing so (1T'-MoTe2 in my case)we are chaning the phase of the material from 1T'-MoTe2 to Td-MoTe2 by forcing the planes to be perpendicular.

Comment: @JaafarMehrez - interesting question about the phase change. That sounds like a paper topic - run some calculations and compare the results from the two programs / geometries. Are the results substantially different? Unclear until someone (you?) runs the calculations.

Comment: Well that's actually what I am working on. My intuition is that as far as it is single layer and we are constructing a single-wall tube then there will be no difference between the two phases (yet still I need to confirm with the calculation). However, when we talk about a multi-wall tube, then I think the phase shall be taken into consideration, and in this regard I was not able to build a mult-wall tube using Chiraltube. The produced structure is not reasonable.